# Stream Reader Problem

Tags: c#

I am using `StreamReader` in C#.net for reading RTF files.
It was working, but after certain time, it's not working. Can anyone help me?

My Code is:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory 
                                       + @"\Features.rtf");
string strfeatures = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Now i am getting the following content in `strfeatures` i.e.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.15.1515;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20\par
}
```

I don't know why?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Your reader should be inside a using block to ensure it is closed and disposed after usage - when you say it stops working, what is the error?

Comment: If your code hasnt changed... and it looks fine to me you need to look at the data its accessing, check the path, the data its self, read the stack trace. Better yet post the error and the stack trace.

Comment: "Now I am getting the following content..." and you were expecting what instead?

Comment: "it's not working": why do you say that? As in: what did it do before that it didn't do now? What did you expect? Why is the text you got wrong (it does look like RTF to me)?

Comment: there is no problem with reader - ir fairly reads content of a file. Try ipening your file in notepad - you will see the same result

Answer (score 3):

Your StreamReader and it's result is correct. If you expected another result you are either loading the wrong file or the file contents are different from what you expect.

BTW: The correct way to create a path is by using the Path.Combine method, not by using the + concatenator.

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory looks somewhat fishy. Are you sure you aren't looking for something like Environment.CurrentDirectory?

Comment: a plus for recommending Path.Combine instead of +

Comment: I can read the text files by using the code wat i had given,but unable to read rtf files